# Blocked bot IP in htaccess still visiting website

Tags: .htaccess, bots

I am using a `Xenforo` website to block an IP of a bot (crawler) because it is going wild on the server.

I have added three lines to make this change happen, but they keep crawling my website.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 93.158.178.201

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^YandexBot [OR]
```

This is how my whole `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
#   Mod_security can interfere with uploading of content such as attachments. If you
#   cannot attach files, remove the "#" from the lines below.
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#   SecFilterEngine Off
#   SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #   If you are having problems with the rewrite rules, remove the "#" from the
    #   line that begins "RewriteBase" below. You will also have to change the path
    #   of the rewrite to reflect the path to your XenForo installation.
    #RewriteBase /xenforo

    #   This line may be needed to enable WebDAV editing with PHP as a CGI.
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^YandexBot [OR]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(data/|js/|styles/|install/|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt) - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from 93.158.178.201
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: after your comments and answer, still having Yandex bot on my website...

```
93.158.178.201 - - [23/Sep/2015:13:56:23 +0200] "GET /threads/g%C3%BCnl%C3%BCk-blog2014.8514/page-87 HTTP/1.1" 403 521 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots)"
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that that specific IP address is still visiting your site? The Yandex bot is likely to visit on a range of IPs.

Comment: Yes, I did. Still the same IP's coming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yandex bots have the following `User-Agent` string:

```
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yandex...)
```

From [Yandex support](https://yandex.com/support/search/robots/agent.xml)

> `User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yandex...)` string identifies
>   `Yandex` robots. Robots can send `GET` (for example, `YandexBot/3.0`)
>   and `HEAD` (`YandexWebmaster/2.0`) requests to a server. A reverse DNS
>   lookup can be used to check the authenticity of Yandex robots.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} compatible;\ yandex [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

The `F` flag will forbid the bot to crawl your pages.

Comment: Nope... still not blocking. I added it in </IfModule>

Comment: @Siyah Put it just after `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Nope, not working. See my revised question (last line). Still getting the same IP AND Yandex...

Comment: It is working. Do you see `403 521` there? The **403** means: [Forbidden](https://devdocs.io/http/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

Comment: You are right. Thanks man! I thought they wouldn't come and visit at all... but I suppose it is not working like that (correct?). Thank you!